# Java while loop stopping before all conditions are met

Tags: java

I have a project where my method gets two dates and it keeps adding a day to the method until both dates are equal and  then you can see how far apart the date were by seeing how many times a day was added. My problem is that my while loop is exiting out when the the day condition is met even  though the day, month, and year must all be the same for it to stop working

```
    while (pastDate.getDay() != futureDate.getDay() && 
    pastDate.getMonth() != futureDate.getMonth()  && 
    pastDate.getYear() != futureDate.getYear()){
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `OR` together the conditions in your `while` loop:

```
while (pastDate.getDay() != futureDate.getDay() ||
       pastDate.getMonth() != futureDate.getMonth()  ||
       pastDate.getYear() != futureDate.getYear()) {
    // do something
}
```

In pseudo-code, the logic for the loop when the two dates are *equal* would be:

```
while (day1 == day2 && month1 == month2 && year1 == year2) {
    // ...
}
```

By the DeMorgan's Laws, the opposite of `P AND Q` is `~P OR ~Q`, which would lead the following `while` loop (again in pseudo-code) for when the dates are *not* equal:

```
while (day1 != day2 || month1 != month2 || year1 != year2) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `day1 = day2` be replaced with equality check in pseudo-code?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.equals()`:

```
while (!pastDate.equals(futureDate)) {
    //
}
```

Not only is it more readable, it leaves exactly *how* dates are considered equal to the implementation, which is where OOP best practices says it should be.